# How can I determine which version of Java a systemd service uses?

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to find the version of java used by user when launching a program, there are multiple versions of java available in few systems, and `JAVA_HOME` is not consistently and reliably set.

i am trying to read the unit file of the service/program  and parse the path and check the version of java.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -d64 -Xms512m -Xmx6g -cp 
ExecStart = /usr/bin/java -jar
```

Is there a regex I can use for the purpose? What's an alternate/better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of parsing the service file, inspect the running service's state.**

If you have a running process, you can do a lookup from `/proc` to find out what executables it has open; there's no reason to parse the service file.

```
findServiceExe() {
  local svc pid retval=0 # avoid polluting namespace
  for svc; do
    pid=$(systemctl show "$svc" | awk -F= '$1 == "ExecMainPID" { print $2 }')
    if [[ $pid ]] && kill -0 "$pid"; then
      readlink -f "/proc/$pid/exe" || (( retval |= $? ))
    else
      echo "No actively-running process found for service $svc" >&2; retval=1
    fi
  done
  return "$retval"
}
```

...after which you can use the function like so:

```
$ findServiceExe myJavaService
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/java
```

This is a much better practice, because *the service file itself is not enough information*; you need to read all the various overlay files, `EnvironmentFile`s, etc., to fully understand the context of the process it invokes.

Comment: thank you, this is much easier and served my purpose... new to this forum, i am liking this.